# ETH sent to ETC address

Tags: cpp-ethereum, ethereum-classic

I accidentally sent ALL my ETH on ETC address :(
6 months of mining gone :(
I sent from one exchange to fresh address on another exchange, but on ETC ...
Is there ANY way to track those coins? 
I'm desperate :(
Thanks

**Update**

Bittrex and their Richie Lai found my transaction and manually refunded all my coins. Bittrex and Stack Exchange advice saved my 4-5 months of mining and my health.

Exchange where i sent coins had my private key and they refunded coins.

Comment: First i want to thank all for Your advises :)
Bittrex and their Richie Lai found my transaction and manually refunded all my coins yeeeeee :)
So I wanted to give You an update and to thank You all, and especially to Bittrex and Richie Lai :)
They saved my 4-5 months of mining and my health :) Thank You all again

Comment: i think i have the same problem .. i put all my eth in a etc adress . What can i do ? Can you help me please ?

Comment: As someone advised me , exchange where i sent coins have my private key and they refunded coins....Read all posts here and You will find what to do.  Hope You retrieve Your eths
Bittrex and  Richie Lai saved my A$$....
But unfortunatelly i lost 200+ ETH by someone who hacked my PC and stole my credentials......

Answer (score 14):

At the core, there are no ETC and ETH account addresses. Private keys are equally valid on both chains. But, a contract can be deployed on one chain or the other uniquely and so contract addresses can be chain specific and aren't generated from a private key. It really depends on whether the exchange is using a contract to manage its wallets or private key based accounts, and whether they are automatically replaying transactions (for example if you sent this to poloniex, the tx would be replayed and you'd be credited ETH even though sent to ETC deposit address).

So, really there's no way to know except to contact the exchange and hope they have something in place to handle this.

Comment: Thanks, i sent FROM Poloniex to Bittrex, both customer support told me there is nothing they can do for me :(
Quote:
"unfortunately, your withdraw is on the chain and out of our hands .i am afriad we will not be able to help with this matter "

and
"Hi,

Sorry here is the correct link.

https://bittrex.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/223411407

Unfortunately with the way the ETC/ETH things have played out these coins cannot be credited.

Thank you,"

Comment: It seems unlikely that, as a technical matter, they can't be recovered. What is the address you sent it to? You can check on etherscan if it's an account or a contract. If it's an account, it certainly can be recovered since the private key is equally valid on both chains. Since you sent from poloniex there's no chance for a replay to fix it, but bittrex should be able to manually move the coins. They may choose to steal from you and keep the coins blaming it on technical issues, but there's no nothing technical stopping them from recovering the coin.

Comment: It was fresh created ETC adress on Bittrex.

Comment: 2016-07-27 17:11:59
Address: 0x6895304785c271b827f1990860d5093e30d2a121
Txid: 0xb0bd7a87223f882b636acf87ffb3d95278f0b1df125e7cda75a8bdb702c7bb4f

Comment: https://etherscan.io/address/0x6895304785c271b827f1990860d5093e30d2a121

Comment: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb0bd7a87223f882b636acf87ffb3d95278f0b1df125e7cda75a8bdb702c7bb4f

Comment: Any help  very appreciated :)

Comment: bojan, bittrex has the private key. just ask them kindly to dig it up for you and credit all the ETH to your account.

Comment: Thanks,Bittrex snet me this:
https://bittrex.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/223411407

Comment: First i want to thank all for Your advises :) Bittrex and their Richie Lai found my transaction and manually refunded all my coins yeeeeee :) So I wanted to give You an update and to thank You all, and especially to Bittrex and Richie Lai :) They saved my 4-5 months of mining and my health :)

Thank You all again