# I mistakenly sent ETH from online wallet to ETC hardware wallet address

Tags: transactions, ethereum-classic, ledger-nano-s

I mistakenly sent ETH from my online wallet to my ETC hardware (Ledger Nano S) wallet address. Is there any possibility of recovery? And if yes, how?

Thanks and kindest regards

Comment: have you succeed to get them back?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7595/eth-sent-to-etc-address?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

A Ledger device uses a Hierarchical, Deterministic (HD) addressing scheme, where different "branches" of addresses are generated from one seed. It uses one "branch" for ETH, and a different "branch" for ETC, and doesn't expect to find the one in the other (which is why the coins aren't showing up in the wallet UI for you).

So, your coins are likely safe, and you just need to use a HD-browsing tool like MyEtherWallet to find them.

Head over to https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction and make sure that in the upper-right, you have an ETH network selected (since that's the currency you're looking for).

Choose the Ledger Nano S option for accessing your wallet, and in the top half of the popup that opens, choose the "Ledger (ETC)" option (the `m/44'/60'/160720'/0'` branch). In the lower half of the dialog, look for the address you sent the ETH to (it should show that it has some ETH balance there). If you don't see it, click the "More addresses" link to scan forward in that branch.

Once you've found it, select it and click "Unlock your wallet", and you can use the form it pulls up to send the coins to the proper address.

Answer (score -1):

ETH and ETC accounts have the same key, so you hardware wallet can be used for managing both ETC and ETH. Extract your key from the wallet and use it to transfer money back to original account.

Comment: Hi Randomlogin, thanks for the quick reply. The problem is that I never received the funds on my hardware wallet. In that case how can I transfer the money back? Thanks again!

Comment: Just use the wallet for its direct purpose. Perhaps, your hardware wallet has some kind of manual how to use it and transfer ether, just follow them with the only difference that steps should be done for Ethereum blockchain, not Ethereum Classic.  
The exact steps are different for different wallets, some of them can give you your keyfile and you can import it in Mist or Parity, some do not and operate in another way.