# I sent My ETC to my ETH address on atrezor

Tags: trezor

I sent My ETC to my ETH address on a trezor
I read the explanation here on stackExchange and i understand i need the private keys, but I can't get the private keys on a trezor.
what should I do?

ps I am from the netherlands so sorry for my english

Comment: Related https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17036/i-mistakenly-sent-eth-from-online-wallet-to-etc-hardware-wallet-address

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://myetherewallet.com (double-check this is the right site -- see also [What is the recommended way to safely store Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-safely-store-ether)) which allow you to select different key-derivation paths. Here are [instructions from Ledger](https://ledger.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005200029-I-sent-ETC-on-an-ETH-address-how-can-I-recover-them-):

> 1. Connect you Ledger device, enter your PIN code, enter your Ethereum
>    application and disable the browser support setting
> 2. On your Ledger
>    Wallet Ethereum application, copy your ETC address // Please verify
>    twice that it is the ETC address, not the ETH one.
> 3. On your Ledger
>    device, enable the browser support setting
> 4. Go to MyEtherWallet website
>    (not the Chrome extension plugin)
> 5. Select "ETC" in the top right menu
> 6. Select the "Send Ether" tab
> 7. Select the "Ledger Nano S" option and
>    click on "Connect your Ledger Wallet"
> 8. Select the " m/44'/60'/0''"
>    derivation path (Ledger ETH)
> 9. Select the address where your ETC are. If
>    you don't find the right address, don't forget to click on "More
>    addresses"
> 10. Click on "Unlock your wallet" to display the wallet manager
> 11. Paste your ETC address in the required field and empty your account

The main differences in instructions for Trezor are that you select the Trezor device (instead of Ledger) and that you select

> m/44'/60'/0'/0
> Jaxx, Metamask, Exodus, imToken, TREZOR (ETH) & Digital Bitbox

and

> m/44'/61'/0'/0
> TREZOR (ETC)

for your key derivation paths instead of Ledger ETH.

If you sent ETH to an account associated with ETC on your Trezor, use the Ledger ETC/Trezor ETC derivation paths instead.

You'll know you have correctly performed the steps up to #9 if MyEtherWallet shows an account balance.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your private key with myetherwallet.com

just be careful that you don't visit a phishing site! (Bookmark it to be sure)