# I accidentally sent some ETC to an ETH wallet

Tags: cpp-ethereum, ethereum-classic

I accidentally sent some ETC to an ETH wallet. The transaction was completed, Poloniex told me that they can't do anything. The coins never got to my wallet but went to the ETC blockchain, understandably

Is there a way to point them to a proper ETC wallet from where they are now?

Comment: I have been transacting on a wrong ETH address, similar to mine but wt just a letter different. Can I get my ETH and tokens from the address to my correct ETH wallet. I don't have the private key to that wallet but I have mine. Is it possible to revert these transactions to my correct ETH wallet? Please help

Comment: Please add this as a new question rather than an answer. (Though this has certainly been asked before.) I'm afraid there's likely nothing you can do. In future, never type out addresses by hand :(

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20220)

Answer (score 1):

The owner of the ETH wallet can have access to an ETC wallet using the same keys. You can get in touch with the ETH wallet address owner where you sent the ETC and request them to revert the ETC using a ETC wallet.

P.S: I notice this is a duplicate. [ETH sent to ETC address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7595/eth-sent-to-etc-address)

Comment: thanks so much for your reply!   so , i should use the private keys from where i sent the coins?   to revert the transaction or the receiving address?

Comment: I assume you have the private keys for the ETH wallet you mistakenly sent ETC to. So your ETC is on the ETC network locked with the same priavte keys you use to access the address on the ETH network.

Use the same ETH keys on ETC network to gain ownership on the ETC address and revert the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand properly, try to connect to ETH node in metamask using private key for ETC wallet. Same PK in different blockchains(evm-compatible) will gain access to same account (with same address).

you can find you funs on both blockchains using:

1. https://blockscout.com/etc/mainnet
2. https://etherscan.io/